# android - Сложный item в recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, возможно ли как-то в списках отключить переиспользование 
view? Например, если каждый item в recyclerview имеет разное количество textview, imageview и их порядок, получается, что каждый item уникален. Как тогда быть в этой ситуации и стоит ли вообще использовать список? Как я понял в списках все элементы должны быть похожи друг на друга

Comment: Не использую `RecyclerView` из-за того, что он в библиотеке. Постоянно избегаю библиотек и использую `ListView`

Comment: Я даже `FAB (FloatingActionButton)` создаю без библиотеки. Кстати, в приложении Сообщения в Android Lollipop, в углу не фаб, а `ImageButton`, завернутая во `FrameLayout` :)

Comment: Напишите подробнее, какие у вас item-ы? Вообще все разные? Или только расположения вьюшек?

Comment: @СергейГрушин, item'ы могут быть все одинаковые, а могут быть все разные, самое ближайшее приложение с тем, что я хочу сделать - мобильный клиент pikabu. На картинке. То есть есть общая форма одного item'a (дата, заголовок, теги и кнопки под контентом), а вот контент внутри у всех разный: [скрин приложения](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/il1R1PuMhakAOGinnIONw7bzZnoWgphzQeGD86UaiuTyZoVskfYK367MT0KadrxogVnv=h900-rw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У recycler view адаптера есть такой метод `getItemViewType(int position)`
Где для каждой позиции вы можете задать уникальный тип.
Есть несколько вариантов. например, вы хотите сделать хэдер, тогда можно поступить так

```
int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return VIEW_TYPE_HEADER;
        else
            return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    }
```

Если нужна более сложная логика, тогда вы можете по позиции получать объекты и далее уже исходя их объектов для каждой позиции задавать нужный тип.

Comment: Да, я именно так сейчас и делаю :) Для каждого itema получаю уникальный viewType(ну то есть просто позицию возвращаю), только у меня возникают проблемы, когда я хочу удалить item из списка, не могли бы вы описать логику, что происходит после вызова notifyItemRemoved?

Comment: ну вообще, если вы вызываете у адаптера  notifyItemRemoved, то он попытается перерисовать эту позицию/диапазон позиций, но этот метод следует вызвать, только после удаления элементов из списка объектов.

Comment: да, я сначала удаляю элемент. Не знаю в чем проблема, нужно разбираться более глубоко. А как думаете, если заполнять item вьюхами в onBindViewHolder, это сильно будет на производительность влиять? При таком случае можно будет переиспользовать viewHolder

Comment: в onBindViewHoler уже приходит все переиспользованое. recyclerview этим и хорош, что не нужно беспокоиться о переиспользовании

Comment: в тех списках, где item'ы похожи друг на друга vH может придти для заполнения информацией с другой позиции. Например если item'ы 1 и 5 имеют одинаковый viewType, то для 5 позиции в onBVH может придти vH который соответствовал 1 позиции. А у меня получается каждому item'у соответствует свой viewHolder. Поэтому в onBVH приходит только соответствующий своей позиции vH, после чего он заполняется

Comment: что я предлагаю: создать общую разметку для item'а, ну грубо говоря просто linearLayout. Затем когда viewHodler будет приходить с другой позиции для переиспользования удалять старые view из layout'a и добавлять новые, которые соответствуют нужно позиции, вот и вопрос, насколько это будет плохо

Comment: нет, это не оптимизация.

Comment: Я кажется понял в чем была моя ошибка. Нельзя было просто так viewType привязывать к позиции, это вызывало при обновлении элементов после удаления ошибку, Ваш ответ навел меня на правильные мысли, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

В моей игре нужно было на каждом айтеме показывать текст действия персонажа и эффекты (например, +5 сытости). Так вот, я создал разметку со всеми TextView, которые только могут быть. Через SimpleAdapter отправлял массивы с числами, а где эфыекта нет, отправлял 0. Потом создал свой адаптер и научил его в случае нуля скрывать TextView.

**Вывод**
Создайте разметку со всеми элементами, которые только могут быть. И придумайте систему наподобие моей, чтобы в каждом айтеме отображались только те вью, которые надо показать.

Какие у вас айтемы? Поподробнее